# GXT NumberField not editable

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm using Gxt-2.2.0 and GWT 2.0. And GXT Numberfileds is not editable.

What can I do for editable NumberFields?

Following code is hopeless;

```
NumberField field = new NumberField();
field.setEditable(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take the answer from GXT Development Team.
The simple solution is upgrading Gxt-2.2.0 to GXT-2.2.1. This upgrade solved the problem.

[Source](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119704-NumberField-not-editable-not-accepted-any-number)

Answer (score 0):

It's editable, your code must simply work, the problem seems with the number field implementation.

It accepts only characters from 0-9, seems for some locale setting in your browser, it's sending characters other than 0-9. you can try other browser (in my case it was working in IE and not in Firefox)

Now to solve your problem you have to set the characters it accepts by calling:

```
// They are by default 0-9 change them to your locale numbers
field.setBaseChars("0123456789");
```

if you don't know what are the locale number characters, you can debug in this method in the NumberField class (inspect key variable):

```
protected void onKeyPress(FieldEvent fe) {
    super.onKeyPress(fe);
    char key = (char) fe.getKeyCode();
    if (fe.isSpecialKey(lastKeyCode) || lastKeyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE
        || lastKeyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE || fe.isControlKey()) {
      return;
    }
    if (!allowed.contains(key)) {
      fe.stopEvent();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I know numerfield accepts only numbers and I tried textfield and they accept numbers but numberfields not. Still I tried setBaseChars method but it is not fix my problem. :(

Comment: try to debug in the above method to find out what's happening;;  
for the setBaseChars, don't use it with 0-9 characters, they are the default instead use you locale characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I solve the problem with upgrading GXT to version 2.2.1